# drop data on scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

iam using Devexpress XtraSchedulercontrol with Drag&Drop operation. Iam using a List as DataSource and if i want to create an new Appointment, it is possible Drag&Drop an Appointment from a Gridcontrol. So far so good.

If someone drop an appointment how can i check the authority? I know the AppointmentDrop event and i handle it so that the dropped appointment isnt in my DataSource. But the schedulercontrol show the appointment. I can do

```
Storage.RefreshData()
```

but there is no way. I just dont want to show the Appointment.
The Point is that nobody should be able to create an appointment on sunday or holiday etc.
Cant understand why the appointment get shown, if i dont load it into DataSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the right solution.

```
private void Scheduler_AppointmentDrop(object sender, AppointmentDragEventArgs e)
{
   if (isAllowed)
   {
      MyDataSource.Add(e.EditedAppointment);
   }
}

private void Scheduler_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   SchedulerStorage.RefreshData();
}
```